# chipmunk physics: how to predict the path of a body including bounces

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I need to predict the path of a body, including bounces with other bodies, in chipmunk physics. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post answered my question:

"*Not in general without copying the entire space then stepping the entire thing forward through time. This would be ridiculously expensive.
If you just want to get the path of a bullet bouncing off of static geometry you can represent the bullet using short raycasts and calculate simple elastic collisions from the collision normals. This would be about as expensive as using shape queries.*"

[chipmunk physics forum](http://chipmunk-physics.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1638&sid=56b4ab225b8db127df14945766df4574)